# Cannot get iban from camt_parser rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bank

I just installed the camt_parser gem (https://github.com/Barzahlen/camt_parser)

With the following test program, no way to get the iban out of the substructre "transactions" from the structure "entry" from the structure "statement"

I get the following error:

```
in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined method `iban' for #<Array:0x007f9003a2ce30> (NoMethodError)
```

In the code I see that this class has a field called iban

Here is the code

```
require 'camt_parser'
camt = CamtParser::File.parse 'myCamt.xml'
camt.statements.each do |statement|

    statement.entries.each do |entry|
     # Access individual entries/bank transfers
     puts entry.description
     puts entry.debit
     puts entry.transactions.iban
    end

end
```

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `entry.transactions[0].iban` as per the documentation. Check the [`Transaction#iban`](https://github.com/Barzahlen/camt_parser/blob/f8560b87b29f722d0089d09d1c69dbdebbe6bc5f/lib/camt_parser/general/transaction.rb#L34) method. And the [spec](https://github.com/Barzahlen/camt_parser/blob/f8560b87b29f722d0089d09d1c69dbdebbe6bc5f/spec/lib/camt_parser/general/transaction_spec.rb#L31) how to extract `iban`.

```
let(:transactions)   { ex_entry.transactions }
let(:ex_transaction) { transactions[0] }

# .......

specify { expect(ex_transaction.iban).to eq("DE09300606010012345671") }
```

You called the `iban` on the collection of `Transaction` instances, but it should be on the instance of `Transaction`.